# Instagram access token with invalid error

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

How can I display Instagram images of my account to my website homepage using access token and user id?

I followed this guide and get Instagram access token and user id https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started

With this guide I get my long-lived access token

but when I run below code in PHP

```
$access_token="--elided--";
$photo_count=6;
$json_link="https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?";
$json_link.="access_token={$access_token}&count={$photo_count}";
echo json_link;
```

It shows:

> {"meta": {"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthAccessTokenException", "error_message": "The access_token provided is invalid."}}

How can I show Instagram media on my website?

Comment: it clearly shows your token is invalid.You must need to get access_token using your client_id and client_secret.

Answer (score 0):

That guide didn't work for me either. Eventually, I figured this out following the procedure [described here](https://www.gsarigiannidis.gr/instagram-feed-api-after-june-2020/).

A few key points to keep in mind:

- Tokens are being generated from Facebook for Developers
  , with no need for a post request like before.
- To fetch the photos, you need to make more than one call to the API: One for fetching the photos' IDs and then, one separate call for each ID to get the actual data (permalink, image URL, caption, etc).
- There is a limit to the calls that you can make per hour, which, as I realized, can be easily reached on a site with moderate traffic. So, you need to somehow cache the results (on WordPress, I used a transient for that, which seems to work fine).
- The token expires after 60 days and you need to refresh it on time for your app to keep working.

Answer (score 0):

Im kind of late but perhabs try to use different API URL. I was also stuck on this problem, trying to use

> https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?...

But later found this address

> https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=media_url,media_type&access_token=...

It works for me with this URL. [Other stuff to put into fields=](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/media)

I would reccomend testing with either curl in cmd or downloading [Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/)

Also if you followed that guide, you'll end up with short-lived token. There is a way to exchange it for long-lived token in [this tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/long-lived-access-tokens/)

But all you really need to do is get the URL ready

```
https://graph.instagram.com/access_token?grant_type=ig_exchange_token&
client_secret={client_secret}&
access_token={token}
```

where

- client_secret is your instagram secret (developers.facebook.com => my apps =>  => on the left panel click "Instagram basic display")
- token is that short-lived token you get from the tutorial mentioned in question ([this one](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started))